# Trying to draw in UIView

Tags: objective-c, ios, cgrect

Hi I am trying to draw some .png images stored in sandbox and the output the text in UIView. My code is:

```
-(void)setItemDetails:(ItemShow *)itmShow
{
   if(theItem!=itmShow)
    {
      [theItem release];
       theItem=itmShow;
      [theItem retain];
    }
  UIImage *rImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"years"];
[[UIColor blackColor] set];
[rImage drawInRect:CGRectMake(55.0, 22.0, 17.0, 17.0)];

[[UIColor brownColor] set];

[theItem.itemYear drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(7.0,19.0)
                forWidth:100
                withFont:[UIFont systemFontOfSize:17.0]
             minFontSize:17.0
          actualFontSize:NULL
           lineBreakMode:UILineBreakModeTailTruncation 
      baselineAdjustment:UIBaselineAdjustmentAlignBaselines];
}
```

That after I call this method in viewDidLoad. Nothing happens. I can't see any images and text on canvas of UIView. What's wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's right, it is exactly what's supposed to happen (nothing), because `viewDidLoad` is not the right place from which you do drawing in iOS. You need to implement a different method:

```
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
CGContextRef myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    // Do your drawing in myContext
}
```

This method of your `UIView` implementation gets called to do the drawing. Trying to draw on the screen from about anywhere else is not going to produce the desired results.

Comment: Frankly to say, I am trying to draw in UIViewController. I tried your code in way: - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGContextRef myContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
    
    
    UIImage *rImage=[UIImage imageNamed:@"years"];
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(10, 10, 300, 400);
    [rImage drawInRect:imageRect];
    [rImage release];
but it didn't draw anything.

Comment: @Nathan The only place intended for drawing on screen is UIView. If you put drawRect in UIViewController, it is going to remain "dead code": the method is not going to be called. You need to subclass UIView and override its drawRect, make an instance of that UIView, and assign that instance to `self.view` of your UIViewController.